# Rails 4: TypeError no implicit conversion of Symbol into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, typeerror, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am relatively new to Rails and I encountered what seems to be a common problem but after reading through all the responses, I cannot seem to make any work for my situation.

I have an app that keeps track of loans and users, and am trying to add a payment feature.  When I try to reach the payment page I encounter this `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String`.  I have tried a bunch of things but nothing seems to work.  I'm not sure if its how I am trying to  access the loan_id or something else.

The error is encountered in PaymentsController#create

Here is my view:

### show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <ul>
      <li><strong>Lender</strong>: <%= @loan.lender.username %></li>
      <li><strong>Borrower</strong>: <%= @loan.borrower.username %></li>
      <li><strong>Amount Remaining</strong>: <%= @loan.amount %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "New Payment", loan_payments_path(@loan.id), :method => :post %></li>
    </ul>
    <section>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_loan_path(@loan) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', loans_path %>
```

### app/controllers/payments_controller

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

  # POST /loans/:loan_id/payments
  def create
    @loan = Loan.find(params[:loan_id])
    @loan.make_payment(payment)
    if @load.save
      redirect_to @loan, notice: "Payment successful"
    else
      redirect_to @loan, alert: "Payment count not be processed"
    end 
  end

  private 

  def payment
    require(:loan).require(:payment)[:payment]
  end

end
```

### routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :loans, shallow: :true do
    resources :payments, only: :create
  end
  root 'static_pages#home'
end



Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)           devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)          devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)      devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)     devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)            devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                   devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)           devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)              devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                   devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                   devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                   devise/registrations#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                   users#index
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)               users#show
           loan_payments POST   /loans/:loan_id/payments(.:format) payments#create
                   loans GET    /loans(.:format)                   loans#index
                         POST   /loans(.:format)                   loans#create
                new_loan GET    /loans/new(.:format)               loans#new
               edit_loan GET    /loans/:id/edit(.:format)          loans#edit
                    loan GET    /loans/:id(.:format)               loans#show
                         PATCH  /loans/:id(.:format)               loans#update
                         PUT    /loans/:id(.:format)               loans#update
                         DELETE /loans/:id(.:format)               loans#destroy
                    root GET    /                                  static_pages#home
```

### Parameters

```
{"_method"=>"post",
 "authenticity_token"=>"VI7rp4N2eHw+tPkY2noD/so9vnGKy/ue06052Vj1f4qidNzgDjZT3aV5v8+XZMs2ZqiUWE0xzAMSQPWltfT6lg==",
 "loan_id"=>"5"}
```

Comment: Can you provide your console log as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in this method:

```
def payment
  require(:loan).permit(:payment)[:payment]
end
```

Fix it to:

```
def payment
  params.permit(:loan_id)
end
```

Read how to permit [`params`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) in Rails.

#### Update:

> Now I get the error `ActionController::ParameterMissing in
>   PaymentsController#create param is missing or the value is empty:
>   loan`

this is normal behavior, because your parameters is empty, you sent nothing to the action, except a `load_id`, to send the `params` with `@load` attributes, pass it to the `loan_payments_path()` helper, like:

```
  <li><%= link_to "New Payment", loan_payments_path(@loan.id, params: { loan_amount: @loan.amount }), :method => :post %></li>
```

And permit it in controller code:

```
def payment
  params.permit(:loan_id, :loan_amount)
end
```

Comment: Now I get the error `ActionController::ParameterMissing in PaymentsController#create` `param is missing or the value is empty: loan`

Comment: this is normal behavior, because your parameters is empty, you sent nothing to the action, except `load_id`

Comment: I'm sorry I do not follow, shouldn't I be sending the loan info corresponding to that loan_id

Comment: thank you!  I am still working on my understanding of params.

Comment: @JeremyThomas now you on a right direction, happy coding!